# Sequence of a sum of two iid random variables again iid?

Tags: probability

I have a sequence $ \{ X_i \} $ that is iid with exponential distribution and another sequence $ \{ Y_i \} $ that is also iid (but unknow distribution). Now we set $$Z_i=X_i + Y_i.$$

> Is then $ \{ Z_i \} $ a sequence of iid random variables?

Comment: Are the $Y_i$ independent of the $X_i$?

Comment: @copper.hat I have deleted my comment because I had missed that the distribution of the $X_i$ is allready determined. I think that 'with respect to $0$' is indeed redundant, but was not sure of that.

Comment: @drhab: I deleted mine after you deleted yours :-).

Comment: no, not in general

Comment: Let it be that $Y_i=-X_i$ if $i$ is odd and $Y_i$ is independent of $X_i$ if $i$ is even. Then $Z_i=0$ if $i$ is odd, but $Z_i\neq 0$ if $i$ is even. The answer to your question is 'no'. What you need are pairs $(X_i,Y_i)$ that are iid.